# Android Shared Element CardView Transition

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, transition, cardview

I've been playing with the shared element transition but I was wondering how to get this effect. I tried sharing both the cardview and imageview elements to another activity but can't achieve the same effect.

https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Vv4SxVSI2DY/VEqQxAf3PWI/AAAAAAAAA7c/mfq7XBrIGgo/s1600/activity_transitions%2B(1).gif

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: check out the reveal animation: https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Comment: Did you every figure this out, I am looking to do something similar as well.

Comment: @RobertVogl Hi mate, do you have any update on that? Were you able achieve this effect ?